# Issues with the pyqt5 label visibility not hiding

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to hide an error label ("*") I have created when a line edit isn't filled in, and then have it disappear when it is filled in, but my program isn't consistent.

An example of it not working:

1. Leave the three slots empty then press the "Add Student" button - a red asterisk will appear next to each one.
2. enter anything into the first ("starting date") line edit then press the "Add Student" button - the red asterisk will disappear.
3. repeat 2 for the first name, but the red asterisk won't disappear.
4. repeat 2 for the last name, but the red asterisk won't disappear for that one either.

```py
import sys
import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qt, QtGui, QtCore

class AddStudent(qt.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        # Set the window to the dimensions of the Screen
        super().__init__()
        screenSize = qt.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(-1)
        self.height = screenSize.height()
        self.width  = screenSize.width()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, self.width, self.height)
        self.setStyleSheet("QLabel {font: 16pt}")

        # Add the buttons, line edits, and table
        self.foundError = False
        self.setup()

        # Display the GUI
        self.setWindowTitle("Add Student")

    def setup(self):
        self.startingDateLabel()
        self.firstNameLabel()
        self.lastNameLabel()
        self.addStudentButton()

    # Button Declarations  
    def startingDateLabel(self):
        self.dateLabel = qt.QLabel(self)
        self.dateLabel.setText("Starting Date:")
        #                         (L/R, U/D, L/R, U/D)
        self.dateLabel.setGeometry(158, 150, 262, 50)
        self.dateLineEdit = qt.QLineEdit(self)
        date = str(datetime.date.today()).split("-")
        today = date[1] + "/" + date[2] + "/" + date[0]
        self.dateLineEdit.setText(today)
        self.dateLineEdit.setGeometry(435, 155, 250, 50)

    def firstNameLabel(self):
        self.firstName = qt.QLabel(self)
        self.firstName.setText("First Name:")
        self.firstName.setGeometry(205, 250, 215, 50)
        self.firstNameLineEdit = qt.QLineEdit(self)
        self.firstNameLineEdit.setGeometry(435, 255, 250, 50)

    def lastNameLabel(self):
        self.lastName = qt.QLabel(self)
        self.lastName.setText("Last Name:")
        self.lastName.setGeometry(208, 350, 212, 50)
        self.lastNameLineEdit = qt.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lastNameLineEdit.setGeometry(435, 355, 250, 50)

    def addStudentButton(self):
        self.addStudent = qt.QPushButton(self)
        self.addStudent.setText("Add Student")
        self.addStudent.setGeometry(800, 1500, 150, 50)
        self.addStudent.clicked.connect(self.addStudentButtonPressed)
        self.addStudent.show()

    def addStudentButtonPressed(self):
        # Check to make sure that everything that needs to be filled out is filled out
        self.errorFound = False

        # Check the starting date
        if (self.dateLineEdit.text() == ""):
            self.error1 = qt.QLabel(self)
            self.error1.setText("*")
            self.error1.setStyleSheet('color: red')
            self.error1.setGeometry(715, 155, 30, 50)
            self.error1.show()
            self.errorFound = True
        else:
            try:
                self.error1.hide()
                self.errorFound = False
            except:
                self.errorFound = False

        # Check the first name slot
        if (self.firstNameLineEdit.text() == ""):
            self.error2 = qt.QLabel(self)
            self.error2.setText("*")
            self.error2.setStyleSheet('color: red')
            self.error2.setGeometry(715, 255, 30, 50)
            self.error2.show()
            self.errorFound = True
        else:
            try:
                self.error2.hide()
                self.errorFound = False
            except:
                self.errorFound = False

        # Check the last name slot
        if (self.lastNameLineEdit.text() == ""):
            self.error3 = qt.QLabel(self)
            self.error3.setText("*")
            self.error3.setStyleSheet('color: red')
            self.error3.setGeometry(715, 355, 30, 50)
            self.error3.show()
            self.errorFound = True
        else:
            try:
                self.error3.hide()
                self.errorFound = False
            except:
                self.errorFound = False

    # Run the window
    app = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = AddStudent()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `self.errorFound` (or `self.foundError`)? Do you ever check the value of this anywhere in your `AddStudent` class?

Comment: I also see that you are hard-coding positions for all of the textboxes, labels, and buttons. This actually ended up with the `Add Student` button being off the screen! I would also take a look at `QFormLayout` (also `QBoxLayout` and `QGridLayout` are helpful). This should make positioning things on the screen a *lot* easier. You can learn more about it [here](https://pythonspot.com/pyqt5-form-layout/).

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes to your code:

1. Just a code style thing: I used **snake case** for the variable and function names. This is the standard for python code, with PyQt being an odd exception (likely due to inheriting from a C++ code base).
2. I removed the use of `self.errorFound`. As I hinted in the comments, you never really check the value of this anywhere. While it might be useful to have a single `self.errorFound` if you just wanted to know if **any** of the user inputs were wrong, **a single boolean couldn't tell you which input was wrong**. I just simply check if the text for the user input is empty every time the `submit` function is called.
3. I used the `QFormLayout` class to position the widgets on the screen. This removes all of the guesswork and math of typing in absolute coordinates of where a widget should belong. It also prevents widgets from "disappearing" if the window is too small. This comes with the limitation that **each row can only hold two widgets**. For this reason, I ditched the asterisk in favor of just coloring the QLabel for the corresponding wrong input. This can be worked around with `QGridLayout` or, if you like the `QFormLayout`, with nested `QHBoxLayout` objects per each field. Let me know if the asterisk is needed.

With all that out of the way, here is updated code:

```
import sys
import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qt, QtGui, QtCore

class MyApp(qt.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        screenSize = qt.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry(-1)

        self.setup()
        self.setWindowTitle("My Awesome App!")

    def setup(self):
        self.form = qt.QGroupBox("Add Student")
        self.form_layout = qt.QFormLayout()

        self.create_date_input()
        self.create_first_name_input()
        self.create_last_name_input()
        self.create_submit_button()
        self.form.setLayout(self.form_layout)

        self.setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form)

    def create_date_input(self):
        self.date_label = qt.QLabel("Starting Date:")
        self.date_entry = qt.QLineEdit(self)
        date = str(datetime.date.today()).split("-")
        today = date[1] + "/" + date[2] + "/" + date[0]
        self.date_entry.setText(today)

        self.form_layout.addRow(
            self.date_label, 
            self.date_entry,
        )

    def create_first_name_input(self):
        self.first_name_label = qt.QLabel("First Name:")
        self.first_name_entry = qt.QLineEdit(self)
        self.form_layout.addRow(
            self.first_name_label, 
            self.first_name_entry,
        )

    def create_last_name_input(self):
        self.last_name_label = qt.QLabel("Last Name:")
        self.last_name_entry = qt.QLineEdit(self)
        self.form_layout.addRow(
            self.last_name_label, 
            self.last_name_entry,
        )

    def create_submit_button(self):
        self.submit_button = qt.QPushButton(self)
        self.submit_button.setText("Add Student")
        self.submit_button.clicked.connect(self.submit)
        self.form_layout.addRow(self.submit_button)

    def submit(self):
        default_color = "color: black"
        error_color = "color: red"
        date_color = default_color
        first_name_color = default_color
        last_name_color = default_color

        #really should validate if this is a date, not just if it is empty
        if (self.date_entry.text() == ""):
            date_color = error_color

        if (self.first_name_entry.text() == ""):
            first_name_color = error_color

        if (self.last_name_entry.text() == ""):
            last_name_color = error_color

        self.date_label.setStyleSheet(date_color)
        self.first_name_label.setStyleSheet(first_name_color)
        self.last_name_label.setStyleSheet(last_name_color)

app = qt.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MyApp()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! That looks much cleaner and more efficient! I appreciate your time and efforts.

Comment: Using the QFormLayout, can I input a table as well?

Comment: @MatthewWilkinson Do you mean something like a [QTableWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtablewidget.html)? There should be nothing to stop you from adding any type of widget to any qt layout object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible solution; while it might seem a bit more complicated than [the other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56944868/2001654) proposed by CodeSurgeon, it is much more extensible to my opinion - and somehow a bit more elegant.

The catch here is the subclass of QLineEdit that embeds a child QLabel, which is made visible only if there's text in the field. The `resizeEvent` override has been added to ensure that the "*" label is always correctly placed whenever the window is resized.
There are many advantages to this approach, but the most important is that subclassing the "main" widget, instead of creating a new one that embeds other widgets, automatically exposes all of its methods and properties.

So, all of this allows you to add as many [text] fields as you want and enables/disables the submit button only if every one of them has some content in it.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class MyLineEdit(QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # the "invalid" label *has* to be a child of this QLineEdit
        self.invalidLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('*', self)
        self.invalidLabel.setStyleSheet('color: red;')
        spacing = 2
        # get default margins and re-set them accordingly
        self.leftMargin, self.topMargin, self.rightMargin, self.bottomMargin = self.getContentsMargins()
        self.rightMargin += self.invalidLabel.minimumSizeHint().width() + spacing
        self.setContentsMargins(self.leftMargin, self.topMargin, self.rightMargin + spacing, self.bottomMargin)
        self.textChanged.connect(self.setValid)
        self.setValid(self.text())

    def setValid(self, text):
        self.invalidLabel.setVisible(not bool(text))

    def isValid(self):
        return bool(self.text())

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.invalidLabel.setGeometry(self.width() - self.rightMargin, self.topMargin, 
            self.invalidLabel.minimumSizeHint().width(), self.height() - self.topMargin - self.bottomMargin)


class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        self.form = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Add Student")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form)
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        self.form.setLayout(self.formLayout)

        self.fields = []
        self.create_field('Starting Date:', defaultValue=QtCore.QDate.currentDate().toString('MM/dd/yyyy'))
        self.create_field('First Name:')
        self.create_field('Last Name:')
        self.create_submit_button()

    def create_field(self, label, defaultValue=''):
        field = MyLineEdit(defaultValue)
        self.fields.append(field)
        field.defaultValue = field.text()
        self.formLayout.addRow(label, field)
        field.textChanged.connect(self.checkFields)

    def create_submit_button(self):
        self.submitButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Add Student')
        self.formLayout.addRow(self.submitButton)
        self.submitButton.clicked.connect(self.submit)
        self.submitButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.checkFields()

    def checkFields(self):
        self.submitButton.setEnabled(all(field.isValid() for field in self.fields))

    def submit(self):
        # doSomething([field.text() for field in self.fields)
        for field in self.fields:
            field.setText(field.defaultValue)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w = MyApp()
w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

As already pointed out, you should really think about validating the date contents (as one could enter anything there) since you are using a line edit.
The better solution is to use a QDateEdit, but you'll need to subclass it as I did with QLineEdit and create a separate `create` function, and obviously it will be "ignored" in the submit "validation" as QDateEdit fields automatically allows valid date inputs.
Otherwise you could use a QValidator, but it would be the proverbial pain in the a**, mainly because QDateTime already provides validation and a nice calendar view by using `setCalendarPopup(True)`, and validating a date through regular expression is really annoying.